# Why is a user checking a box different than doing it programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm playing around in the Chrome Dev Tools console and I noticed that when I physically click a checkbox with my mouse and when I call `$('input.checkbox').prop('checked',true)`, the end result is aesthetically the same but not in the back end.

For example let's say there's a form that submits the user's gender. If I click the checkbox next to 'Male' and hit submit, the system'll record the change, but if I were to call `$('input.checkbox#male').prop('checked',true)` and hit submit it doesn't record the change in the back end.

Does doing it programmatically not change the state or is there something on their end that specifically was done to forbid changing the state programmatically?

Comment: Is it possible that there is a `click` event listener somewhere in the code? Doing this programmatically shouldn't make a difference. (in terms of the data that is submitted).

Comment: Try adding `$('input.checkbox').trigger('change')` and seeing if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's likely a click or change listener that does something necessary before submitting the results. Try using `$('input.checkbox#male').click()` instead of `$('input.checkbox#male').prop('checked',true)`

Answer (score 4):

That is most likely because event listeners `onClick`, `onChange` and friends are only triggered on user actions, not when you change some state programmatically.

The actual form data that gets submitted should be the identical, though, no matter how you arrived at setting the form input values, and how you trigger the submission. In your case, maybe you have some event handlers setting some hidden fields?